# Export Materialized View from postgresql as a table?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view

I have a materialized view I created in Postgresql. I was wondering is there a way to pg_dump the materialized view as if they were tables, so when I import them into another database it sees it as tables rather than a view created from other tables?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is a single-step way to do this.  Are you trying to do this with one MV, or with a whole database full of them?

To get the proper CREATE TABLE statement with all the column types, you could do this:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy1 (like mv1 including indexes);
```

And then use `pg_dump -t dummy1 > mv1.sql` to get the CREATE TABLE statement.

To get the data, you would do:

```
\copy (select * from mv1) to mv1.txt
```

You would then have to stitch the two files together with a name change from 'dummy1' to 'mv1' in the first file, to get the definition and the data to be combined in one replayable file.

Answer (score 1):

Agree that there's no direct way. What I would do is the following steps:

(1) save the Materialized View as a CSV file (see screenshot below)

(2) create a new table

(3) import the saved CSV

[image]